# Finance metaphors for relationships

Tags: meaning, idiom

I've recently read that there are quite a few metaphors describing relationships between humans that are taken from the financial sector. However, examples were very scarce.

The best one being "investieren", I have a hard time coming up with other examples. Any suggestions?

**P.S.** When I read this, it was actually about the English language. I'm trying to find out whether this is the case in German, too.

Comment: I don't know any financial metaphors for relationships. And I actually live in Germany since I was born. MS Word also doesn't know any.

Comment: Give us a link to the English list, so it will be easier to find equivalent words in German

Comment: invest, value, priceless, bankrupt. That's all.

Comment: Inwiefern ist **investieren** ein **Verhältnis**? Investieren ist ein Verb, während Verhältnis ein Substantiv ist. Das kann so nix geben.

Comment: Na ja, man kann auch im Deutschen _in eine Beziehung viel investiert haben_ zum Beispiel. Aber sonst …

Comment: Have they really been taken from financial expressions, words, or concepts/thoughts? valuable is not expensive, I can value sth. without having money in mind. value is from Old French valoir, to be worth. invest is from "clothe with the insignia of a rank", "endow with authority". Price, archaic: value, worth. Of course, I do not know when these words came into use in which sense, but we need to consider the idea that some of these were adopted by the financial world later to name the things they need to deal with. Bankrupt seems like a good example.

Comment: relationship ist eine Beziehung zwischen Menschen, es hat nichts mit dem Komparativ von Adjektiven zu tun. Franz sucht nach Wörtern, mit denen man  zwischenmenschliche Beziehungen beschreiben kann, und die der Finanzwelt entnommen sind.

Comment: `Investieren` alleine ist aber noch nicht die Metapher. Gefühle/Zeit/Geld in eine Beziehung investieren wäre eine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Die Unschuld für nach der Hochzeit **aufsparen**.
- Meine Geduld mit ihrer Mutter **trägt Zinsen**.
- Seine Hobbies hat er der Frau zuliebe **abgeschrieben**.
- In Sachen Treue gibt sie ihm **keinen Kredit** mehr.
- Auf der Beziehung lastet eine **Hypothek**.

Ich glaube die einzige Schwierigkeit besteht, sich an finanzwirtschaftliche Floskeln zu erinnern. Metaphern sind kontextagnostisch, d.h. wenn man eine Metapher hier und da einsetzen kann, dann wahrscheinlich auch in Beziehungen.

- Ich zahle es Dir in **gleicher Währung** heim.
- Nach der Ehekrise machten sie **Inventur**.
- Ich ziehe nach 3 Jahren Vaterschaft eine vorläufige **Bilanz**.
- Sie **verbuchte** meinen Seufzer als Erfolg.
- Ich habe noch 2 Jugendlieben auf der **hohen Kante**.

Der Adressat der Metapher muss diese natürlich entschlüsseln können. Mit komplizierten Konstrukten wie mündelsicheren Anleihen ist es recht schwer ein griffiges Beispiel zu konstruieren.

Comment: Oder kurz gesagt: Es gibt (fast) keine. Dort, wo die Anwendung noch akzeptabel klingt, hat das entsprechende Wort (zufällig?) auch eine "non-financial" Bedeutung. Alle anderen klingen bestenfalls gestellzt, aber sonst eher dem Zwecke dienend aufgemacht. Einzig "auf der hohen Kante" und "gleicher Währung", wobei ersteres eh eine Redewendung ist, im gegebenen Kontext aber seeeeeehr merkwürdig klingt.

Answer (score 3):

Ich hätte da:

> Jemandem eine Rechnung aufmachen.

und:

> Wir werden abrechnen.